# Delete string of text of output using SED

Tags: sed

I have went to https://sed.js.org/ and https://regex101.com and finally https://tecadmin.net/delete-a-line-containing-specific-string-using-sed/. I am unable to delete the front end and the trailing / in a directory string. This would be set to a variable in a bash. Expecting dir=$(sed ...)

Folder: /config/folder/donwloads/Video/Epoc/

I would like to only have the exact test of "Epoc" as the output. I am unable to figure this out using this above resources.

I have tested the string below using both the sed.js.org website and my bash prompt.

```
echo "/config/folder/downloads/Epoc/" | sed 's/.*[downloads]//'
```

but let with "c/" as the output.

I have tried to at least remove the trailing / at end .

```
echo "/config/folder/downloads/Video/Epoc/" | sed 's/.*[Video]//' | sed '/\//d'
```

Then I get nothing for output.

Am I using the wrong command to do this or just using the command in the incorrect way?

Output of Epoc only with no trailing or fronted "/"

Comment: `basename "/config/folder/downloads/Epoc/"`

Comment: `echo "/config/folder/downloads/Video/Epoc/" | sed 's:.*/\(.*\)/$:\1:'`

Comment: `[`...`]` denotes a character class (ie. select single character that matches any of the ones listed). `[downloads]` contains `o` so matches the `o` in `Epoc`

Comment: cf. https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/basename.html

Comment: `sed '/\//d'` means "search line for a slash; if found, delete entire line"

Comment: Remove first last `/` and then everything up to last `/`: `| sed 's|/$||; s|.*/||'`

Answer (score 2):

What goes wrong with your regex:

1. `s/.*[downloads]//` : this performs a greedy search for anything before any of the letters "d","o","w","n","l","a" and "s". It does not search for the word "download", this would be: `s/.*downloads//`. Anything between square brackets means a set of characters, but represents a single character. Hence the result is `c/` because of the letter `o` in "Epoc".
2. The same applies to the string `s/.*[Video]//`
3. The string `/\//d` means delete every line that has a `/` in it.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n 's/.*[/]\([^/]\+\)[/]\?$/\1/p' file
```

Use greed `.*` to search for the last or last but one `/`, then capture anything which is not a `/` until the last optional `/` before the end of the line.

Alternative:

```
sed -nE 's/.*\/([^/]+)\/?$/p' file
```